# What to put in DB_HOST .env file laravel when deployed?

Tags: laravel

For the first time i am deploying my project in a live server.
Everything works file in local but when i deployed in the servier it gives me error like
***"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'apariwar_a4family'@'ip113.ip-188-165-124.eu' (using password: YES)"***

Env file looks like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mydomain.com
DB_PORT=3306
```

rest of the DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD everything is correct.

Also, when i hit this ip(ip113.ip-188-165-124.eu) address from 'apariwar_a4family'@'ip113.ip-188-165-124.eu' then it shows other domain which is not mine.

I have tried everything like config:clear, optimize:clear etc etc

Comment: Depends on your hosting provider, should ask them. Is your database user setup correct?

Comment: With every hosting service I've come across the hostname is always localhost(127.0.0.1), especially if you are using a shared hosting service instead of a dedicated server.


Use: `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 127.0.0.1. It must work if there is no other problem.